# Parse JSON Object Array Data With PHP

Tags: php, json

Why does `ac` return `NULL` here?  I've verified with `var_dump` it has values

```
$data = array(
    'ac' => $cl->l->ac->dn,
    );

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        echo "The $key is: ". json_encode($value);
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

This is the format it's in

```
  "ac": [
    {
      object (Category)
    }
  ]
```

Comment: the ``var_dump`` showed it was Restaurant

Comment: inside the ``foreach`` or above it?